# Password hash and salt using bcrypt in React Native (Expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, bcrypt

I have a react native expo application where I want to implement authentication storing user password hash and salt.
For this purpose, I am trying to use bcryptjs library.
Here is the code I am using to generate a salt:

```
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
```

However, I am getting an error with this messages at the abovementioned line:

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-crypto\index.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNRandomBytes.seed')
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:34:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:165:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:177:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:437:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:388:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:132:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:131:4 in flushedQueue
```

This is the package.json content I have:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install crypto,assert,url,stream,events --hack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "@tradle/react-native-http": "^2.0.0",
    "assert": "^1.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.1.4",
    "console-browserify": "^1.1.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "convert-array-to-csv": "^2.0.0",
    "dns.js": "^1.0.1",
    "domain-browser": "^1.1.1",
    "dropbox": "^10.23.0",
    "events": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "~43.0.0",
    "expo-crypto": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-file-system": "^13.0.3",
    "expo-media-library": "~13.0.3",
    "expo-print": "~11.0.4",
    "expo-random": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "https-browserify": "^0.0.1",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "path-browserify": "^0.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.0",
    "punycode": "^1.2.4",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-level-fs": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-os": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-tcp": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-udp": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "readable-stream": "^1.0.33",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "string_decoder": "^0.10.31",
    "timers-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "tty-browserify": "^0.0.0",
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "util": "^0.10.4",
    "vm-browserify": "^0.0.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.3.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "react-native": {
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  },
  "browser": {
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this? What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you testing the app? You'll need a native environment to run code through `react-native-crypto` (with the due linking). You can run a development profile with EAS: https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/

Comment: @Nelloverflow I am running it on Android Virtual Device. Can you please explain why I need the react-native-crypto as I am using bcryptjs?

Comment: Some NPM packages depend on Node Native  module . Try this package designed for https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/

Comment: That package probably isn't suited for his needs if he needs salting. Try and see if this one works with the current version of Expo: https://github.com/andreshsingh/bcrypt-react-native You'll most likely need in any case something that's suited for React-Native/Expo with a native implementation if the pure JS version you're using isn't behaving nicely

Comment: I'm not going to delve into the fact that from the looks of how you described things it wouldn't be right to hash stuff on the client-side of things anyway but at the end of the day that's your pick

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
import BcryptReactNative from 'bcrypt-react-native';

// ...
try{

const salt = await BcryptReactNative.getSalt(10);
const hash = await BcryptReactNative.hash(salt, 'password');
const isSame = await BcryptReactNative.compareSync('password', hash);
} catch(e) {
  console.log({ e })
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work in react native. Note I installed bcrypt-react-native using npm, I received following error message  Property 'hash' doesn't exist